# Expected Area of Randomly Made Triangle

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-probability, triangles

Say we have a piece of length one, and then we draw twice from a bin of sticks in which there are an infinite amount of sticks with lengths evenly distributed on $[0,1]$. In cases where a triangle can be formed, what is the expected area of the formed triangle?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

Comment: This is the wrong forum for your question, which essentially asks for the value of a (n iterated) definite integral (Heron's formula for the integrand) over a simply described domain.  Gerhard "Web Search May Be Faster" Paseman, 2017.10.18.

Comment: Some double integrals are nontrivial . . . this one might even be a K3 period.  Are you sure you know how to evaluate the integral that arises here? (cf. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206352)

Comment: It may be impossible to solve the integral exactly.  However, the question as posed does not shed light on what has been tried or assumed.  You might turn it into a good question with a good answer,  but let's see something more from the original poster.  Gerhard "For Example, What's My Motivation?" Paseman, 2017.10.18.

Comment: Seems to be a natural enough question that "motivation" isn't really needed,  but yes, it would still be nice to have some indication of what if anything the original poster tried.

Comment: This is not easy.  Even with one side of length 1, one side of length 1/2, and one random side, Mathematica gets confused about whether its answer is real:$$\mathtt{Integrate[(Sqrt[(1+a^2+b^2)^2 - 2 (1+a^4+b^4)]) \ /.\  
  a -> 1/2, \{b, 1/2, 1\}]}$$$$1/4 (Sqrt[5/3] + 5 I EllipticE[1/9] - 5 I EllipticE[ArcSin[2], 1/9] + 
   4 I EllipticF[ArcSin[2], 1/9] - 4 I EllipticK[1/9])$$And Mathematica gives up on the first of two integrals in a natural formulation for the problem as stated:$$\mathtt{Integrate[Sqrt[(1 + a^2 + b^2)^2 - 2 (1 + a^4 + b^4)], \{b, 1 - a, 1\}, 
 Assumptions -> 0 < a < 1]}$$

Comment: The Wikipedia link suggests a version where (with a=1 and b greater than c) an integral to try involves integral from c =1-b to b of half of sqrt( c^2 - ((1+c^2 -b^2)/2)^2).  Does Mathematica do anything with that?  Gerhard "Not Ready For Cylindrical Coordinates" Paseman, 2017.10.18.